# How to add some shortcut for editing in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, shortcut

I would like to add some "commands for editing" in TeXstudio. For instance in the menu "TI" on the left which stands for 'TikZ', there is some "commands for éditing" TikZ commands, you click on it and you have some squeleton of commands in your source file, and you just have to modify it to custom it.

I would like to add some personnal "commands for editing". Is it possible to do it in TeXstudio, and if yes, how do we do that ?

Comment: What does 'PR' stands for ? Which menu do you need exactely for "user central and toolbar customisation area" ?

Comment: Perfect for me. Thanks a lot.